# using ravendb to store image

Tags: c#, winforms, ravendb

I'm using ravendb with winforms application. Now I want to add into my entity Book property CoverPhoto which shold be of type image. How to store image in raven embedded database?

any tutorials, links please.

Thanks

Comment: Storing images in a database is not a good idea.  Consider file storage with paths in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You store it as an attachment to a document.

http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/attachments